Postgresql logical replication suddenly gone
We have a logical replication set up (pg 13) with publication <> subscription. All good, most of the time.
But every two weeks or so I get a notification (internal replication monitoring) that the replication is 'out of sync' with the underlying message that there is no subscription on the receiving machine. As far as I can see there is no event that can be linked to this. And it is not being remove manually.
What reasons could there be for this?
Update: Logs
Main:
10:41:35.486 LOG:  received replication command: IDENTIFY_SYSTEM
10:41:35.486 STATEMENT:  IDENTIFY_SYSTEM
10:41:35.488 LOG:  received replication command: START_REPLICATION SLOT "pub_20240606_0838" LOGICAL DB6/94B7D960 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_20240606_0838"')
10:41:35.488 STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "pub_20240606_0838" LOGICAL DB6/94B7D960 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_20240606_0838"')
10:41:35.489 LOG:  starting logical decoding for slot "pub_20240606_0838"
10:41:35.489 DETAIL:  Streaming transactions committing after DB6/94B7BA68, reading WAL from DB6/94B7B980.
10:41:35.489 STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "pub_20240606_0838" LOGICAL DB6/94B7D960 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_20240606_0838"')
10:41:35.489 LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at DB6/94B7B980
10:41:35.489 DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
10:41:35.489 STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "pub_20240606_0838" LOGICAL DB6/94B7D960 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_20240606_0838"')
10:41:40.544 LOG:  received replication command: IDENTIFY_SYSTEM
10:41:40.544 STATEMENT:  IDENTIFY_SYSTEM
10:41:40.546 LOG:  received replication command: START_REPLICATION SLOT "pub_20240606_0838" LOGICAL DB6/94B7D960 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_20240606_0838"')
10:41:40.546 STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "pub_20240606_0838" LOGICAL DB6/94B7D960 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_20240606_0838"')
10:41:40.548 LOG:  starting logical decoding for slot "pub_20240606_0838"
10:41:40.548 DETAIL:  Streaming transactions committing after DB6/94B7D960, reading WAL from DB6/94B7B980.
10:41:40.548 STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "pub_20240606_0838" LOGICAL DB6/94B7D960 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_20240606_0838"')
10:41:40.549 LOG:  logical decoding found consistent point at DB6/94B7B980
10:41:40.549 DETAIL:  There are no running transactions.
10:41:40.549 STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "pub_20240606_0838" LOGICAL DB6/94B7D960 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_20240606_0838"')
10:41:40.555 LOG:  could not send data to client: Connection reset by peer
10:41:40.555 CONTEXT:  slot "pub_20240606_0838", output plugin "pgoutput", in the change callback, associated LSN DB6/94B92E08
10:41:40.555 STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "pub_20240606_0838" LOGICAL DB6/94B7D960 (proto_version '1', publication_names '"pub_20240606_0838"')
10:41:45.595 LOG:  received replication command: IDENTIFY_SYSTEM
10:41:45.595 STATEMENT:  IDENTIFY_SYSTEM

Replica:
10:41:35.422 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_81203126_primary"
10:41:35.422 DETAIL:  Key (version)=(20240501095011) already exists.
10:41:35.434 LOG:  logical replication apply worker for subscription "sub_20240606_0838" has started
10:41:35.447 LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 42) exited with exit code 1
10:41:35.495 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_81203126_primary"
10:41:35.495 DETAIL:  Key (version)=(20240501095011) already exists.
10:41:35.498 LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 19634) exited with exit code 1


PostgreSQL doesn't automatically drop subscriptions. The best you can do is log statements in PostgreSQL and see when and by whom the subscription is dropped.

I updated the question with log output @LaurenzAlbe

That log is incomplete: detail to what? There must be earlier, interesting messages. Try setting log_replication_commands = on on the subscriber. Perhaps you can catch something. At any rate, the cause cannot be PostgreSQL itself.

@LaurenzAlbe I added the logs from main and replica, the moment the replication goes wrong.

The messages say nothing about a missing subscription. How can that be?

@LaurenzAlbe I might have found the curlpit here: when running our migrations we run them for the subscriber as well because schema changes are not replicated. But the migrator also writes the migrations to a schema_migrations table on target database. That triggerd the unique constraint.

Still, that doesn't explain why there is no subscription object.
